# flutter how to create custom MaterialColor shades

Tags: flutter, dart, class, themes

I have a class like CustomColors and I have navy color inside this class. It is working good but not woking as my wanting. I want to select only created color for each color. For example when I select a color for widget. I can see every shade numbers such shade200, shade300, shade800, shade900. But I did not create shade900 for the navy color.
The image is more explanatory you can look it. I don't want to see shade600, shade700 or any other suggestions. How can I do this or how can I do this with another class using. I only want to select color inside color. like CustomColors.green.shade300 or CustomColors.green.colorname.

[image]